# How to include a transaction in a selected block/or at particular time

Tags: ether, web3.py, blocks

There is this particular function of the project which is required to be triggered by someone on BSC blockchain manually at a particular time to execute certain functions. A person who gets to the function of the contract first, gets the rewards.

So I wrote a python script to hit the function and time it (time to call the contract). Most of the time, I miss the block. After going through the explorer over the few days, I found this wallet who hits the contract at the right block and even pay higher fees to get his trxn is executed firat within the block. And he/she does that consistently.
Wondering how he/she is so of getting his trxn in the right block, considering the high fee he/she would lost if he doesnt get to it first.

Wondering how he/she is doing it?

Is it possible to send a trxn to be executed in a block we want?
If he/ahe timing it, thats a risk cause even 1 sec delay due to Internet speed could make him miss it (and the guy never miss it)

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ethereum side, you could utilize something like Flashbots (MEV), but that's not possible in BSC side. So, as far as I can tell, there are basically only two possible approaches:

1. Make the transaction through a contract which reverts the transaction if it's not in the right block. This doesn't help in getting it in to the right block, but helps in not getting it to succeed in the wrong block. But this may not help anything in your case, since you said the right functionality can anyway only be called in the right block
2. Play with gas price, timing and connectivity. In theory, the better connectivity you have (more nodes connected), the faster mining nodes see your transactions. And high gas price gives them incentive to include your transaction first.

But as far as I can tell, there is no certain way to do this in BSC.

Comment: Thanks mate. Will work on the timing and hope that guy miss it some day. Cheers :)